# Good tutorials/books starting amazon EC2 java REST web service

Tags: rest, architecture, amazon-web-services

I need to build a very scalable REST web service that will be consumed both by mobile apps, clients surfing the web, servers, etc...

Now as you can imagine this is a rather large task and I have no idea where to start, so I wonder if there are any good tutorials or books to help me on my way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good starting point would be reading the "REST API - Design Rulebook" by "Mark Masse" published by  O'Reilly Media, Inc.